# Remove unused js/css references

Tags: css

I'm new to web development and am using Laravel. For this, I purchased a HTML admin page template which already included Laravel (so basically Laravel plus the theme in HTML already set up). Now I'm using some elements from everywhere inside the template and I ended up having **heavily long** reference lists. I don't think this is necessary or even considered good code (rather HTML markup), and I even tried to remove some of the references, but then for some reason some elements of the page do not properly work anymore.

For example, I choose a certain button element from a HTML page included in the template, I copy the code and paste it inside where I need it. I also copy the references, but not necessarily all the references (because there were not only buttons on the page). However, not having -all- the references ended in a messed-up page with few things working. I wonder if there is like any tool which automatically removes these statements since I feel that the following is ridiculous compared to the actual size/content of the page (which is merely a form to enter your personal data):

```
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assets/vendors/bootstrapvalidator/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css')}}"/>
    <!--page level styles-->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assets/css/pages/wizards.css')}}"/>
    <!--End of page styles-->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assets/vendors/inputlimiter/css/jquery.inputlimiter.css')}}" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assets/vendors/bootstrap-colorpicker/css/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.css')}}" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assets/vendors/jquery-tagsinput/css/jquery.tagsinput.css')}}" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assets/vendors/daterangepicker/css/daterangepicker.css')}}" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assets/vendors/datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css')}}" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assets/vendors/bootstrap-timepicker/css/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css')}}" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assets/vendors/bootstrap-switch/css/bootstrap-switch.min.css')}}" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assets/vendors/jasny-bootstrap/css/jasny-bootstrap.min.css')}}" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assets/vendors/datetimepicker/css/DateTimePicker.min.css')}}" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assets/vendors/j_timepicker/css/jquery.timepicker.css')}}" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assets/vendors/clockpicker/css/jquery-clockpicker.css')}}" />
    <!-- end of plugin styles -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assets/css/pages/colorpicker_hack.css')}}" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assets/vendors/bootstrap-switch/css/bootstrap-switch.min.css')}}" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assets/vendors/switchery/css/switchery.min.css')}}" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assets/vendors/inputlimiter/css/jquery.inputlimiter.css')}}"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assets/vendors/chosen/css/chosen.css')}}"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assets/vendors/bootstrap-colorpicker/css/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.css')}}"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assets/vendors/daterangepicker/css/daterangepicker.css')}}"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assets/vendors/datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css')}}"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assets/vendors/bootstrap-timepicker/css/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css')}}"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assets/vendors/bootstrap-switch/css/bootstrap-switch.min.css')}}"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assets/vendors/jasny-bootstrap/css/jasny-bootstrap.min.css')}}"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assets/vendors/fileinput/css/fileinput.min.css')}}"/>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assets/vendors/multiselect/css/multi-select.css')}}"/>
    <!--End of plugin styles-->
    <!--Page level styles-->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assets/css/pages/form_elements.css')}}"/>
```

(Not to forget all the JS at the bottom!)

Comment: Wow, what a mess :)

Comment: Just open all the files in your preferred editor, hit CTRL + H, and replace them all in all open documents, save the files and send them back to server.

Comment: The thing is that you are using a lot of libraries... Making those code necessary! There's not much you can do about it beside minifying everything into one file and trying to avoid using so many different tools

Comment: @Salketer This is true, however, there is reference to JS I think I don't need (for example fileinput.min.css) (there's nothing about file input in my application) which yet had to be copied in its entirety (because certain elements worked only when I copied the entire references). Is there maybe something like a command to recompile everything so these pointless references are not there?

Comment: There is no sure fire way to know if a css file is used or not, since javascript could add elements too and what not. If fileinput is needed, it's because it adds some styling that are used. Remove it, check what element has changed, add it back and look at the element's computed style in your developper tools. You'll be able to find what part comes from it.

Answer (score 1):

Just simply go to Google's developer by clicking Short cut (control + shift+ I) and then go to Audit tab, you will find all the details and performance audit report. From there you can find the used and unused css and JavaScript codes.

Answer (score -1):

You can inspect the particular webpage. During inspecting, you can find out the error/unused portion of css/js files in console. They basically name the unused file with line number.